# Boostrap's accordion doesn't work properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a the following accordion on the github page http://dkalisch.github.io/complexity/ but it doesn't work.

```
              June 14, 2015 - Early submission deadline

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Early submission deadline - for the papers to be published in a Mini-Track proceedings; based on the results of the review process those papers could be also recommended for the special issue.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-default" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

              September 13, 2015 - Deadline to submit presentation/paper for review

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Final deadline for presentation/paper submission to the Symposium. Papers submitted by that date will be considered for publication in the special issue.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">

              November 8, 2015 - Deadline first-round reviews

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        On this day the reviews for the first round are due.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">

              December 13, 2015 - Deadline for revised submission of presentation/papers.

              </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
      <div class="panel-body">
        The improvements to papers that have been accepted with mandatory changes have to be finished and the paper has to be resubmitted by now.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">

              January 31, 2016 - Deadline second-round reviews

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
      <div class="panel-body">
        On this day the reviews for the second round are due.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">

              February 12, 2016 - Deadline camera ready version.

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
      <div class="panel-body">
        A camera ready version of the paper has to be uploaded to the submission system.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSeven">

              May-June, 2016 - Final Publication

            </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSeven">
      <div class="panel-body">
        The special issue will be published between May and June 2016 in <a href="http://tldks.faw.at" target="_blank">TLDKS</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I paste it to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jcawtzr/ then it works.
Does someone have an idea what the problem might be?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery version? you can check your page with `$().jQuery`

Comment: The jQuery version is v.1.11

Comment: what specifically isn't working on your version?

Comment: The accordion doesn't close the open ones and only works for the first click.

Comment: most probably some conflict with some other javascript library used ,try to html comment <!-- --> the unrelated js library (<script src=" ) links and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks jathin. I figured out, that it is a problem with the video sequence at the top of the page. When I remove it, everything works fine. The question is now, how to fix this interference...